# How to work with push notification in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift2, apple-push-notifications

I am developing app using swift 2.2, in my app I need to work with push notification there is no push notification options in my Xcode i know that i need to create certificate from developer portal is there any easy way to work with push notification like using cocoapods instead of creating certificate.

There is no other way means just refer me to follow any official link.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: you might want to check [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for your responses

Comment: Check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive....shall i follow steps involved in firebase????

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

Comment: http://onesignal.com is probably your quickest option to get you up & running.

Comment: This one is also asks for certificate